# How to fix "it doesn't support that" when I query Alexa retrievable property

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-smart-home-skill

I have this endpoint with powerState and connectivity properties both retrievable:

```
    {
        "endpointId": "123",
        "manufacturerName": "abc",
        "friendlyName": "lamp",
        "description": "lamp",
        "displayCategories": [
            "LIGHT"
        ],
        "capabilities": [
            {
                "type": "AlexaInterface",
                "interface": "Alexa.PowerController",
                "version": "3",
                "properties": {
                    "supported": [{
                            "name": "powerState"
                        }],
                    "retrievable": true
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "AlexaInterface",
                "interface": "Alexa.EndpointHealth",
                "version": "3",
                "properties": {
                    "supported": [{
                            "name": "connectivity"
                        }],
                    "retrievable": true
                }
            }
        ],
        "cookie": {}
    }
```

I respond to ReportState request by sending the state of both properties:

```
    {
        "context": {
            "properties": [
                {
                    "namespace": "Alexa.PowerController",
                    "name": "powerState",
                    "value": "ON",
                    "timeOfSample": "2019-01-10T10:17:19.99Z",
                    "uncertaintyInMilliseconds": 50
                },
                {
                    "namespace": "Alexa.EndpointHealth",
                    "name": "connectivity",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "OK"
                    },
                    "timeOfSample": "2019-01-10T10:17:19.90Z",
                    "uncertaintyInMilliseconds": 50
                }
            ]
        },
        "event": {
            "header": {
                "namespace": "Alexa",
                "name": "StateReport",
                "payloadVersion": "3",
                "messageId": "cde",
                "correlationToken": "efg123"
            },
            "endpoint": {
                "scope": {
                    "type": "BearerToken",
                    "token": "ab123"
                },
                "endpointId": "123",
                "cookie": {}
            },
            "payload": {}
        }
    }
```

And I send the same context in the PowerController response.
In the Alexa app I can see my device, turn it on and off and view its state rightly. I can ask Alexa to turn on and off my device and the response in "OK", but if I try to ask:** "Is my device turned on?" ** Alexa answers that **this device doesn't support that**.

The skill language is Italian and PowerController documentation https://developer.amazon.com/it/docs/device-apis/alexa-powercontroller.html says that query is supported.

What am I missing?

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Same issue, but no answer here :-(